# Is there a better word than "Likewise"?

Tags: word-request, adverbs

> All five newspapers rely the same data source, so all are _______ subject to the same filtering.

Is it really "likewise" I have to stick with? It sounds odd...

Comment: How about: definitely?

Comment: As pointed out by @Franck below, it doesn't really need anything, but if I were to put a word in, it would be *therefore*.

Comment: @Jim Good to point out that no word is needed, but I wouldn't insert *therefore* as it seems logically redundant with the preceeding *so.* That's just me, though.

Comment: Do note that it is "rely **on** *something*", not "rely *something*".

Comment: Wouldn't *likewise* actually be out of place here? Maybe it's a British thing. I'd only use it when indicating that one thing is similar to another that was just previously described, e.g. "Paper X is subject to Y filtering, so Paper Z, relying on the same data source, is likewise subject to the same filtering."

Comment: @talmu: I guess that's what I wanted to say when I wrote "it sounds odd" - just that I lack the professional skills to find out what exactly is odd.

Answer (score 14):

To me *likewise* is redundant with *same*, unless your context clearly indicates that one given filtering can be applied in different ways.

As a result, I would simply skip *likewise* and write: *All five newspapers rely on the same data source, so all are subject to the same filtering.*

Comment: +1 I agree, the sentence sounds fine without a word in the blank

Answer (score 1):

I would use "inherently" in this case.

This would help to convey that, due simply to the fact that they use the same data source, it is *expected and usual* that they are subject to the same filtering.

Comment: "Inherently" changes the meaning of the sentence, though: it would mean that filtering is an obvious consequence of using the data source.

Comment: I agree with 200_success, inherently changes the meaning of the sentence

Comment: This could work if the changed meaning is indeed what the OP is trying to convey. Language learners may construct a sentence with one meaning in mind but speakers attempting to correct the construction may assume a different meaning. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just a different thought. With the subject being the data source, there are a lot of adverbs that can be injected into the sentence. The word "likewise" does not fit in the blank spot in the sentence. However, maybe you could write the sentence as

> All five newspapers rely (on) the same data source. Likewise, all newspapers are subject to the same filtering.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip repeating "same" and still mean the same:

All five newspapers rely on the same data source, so they are subject to similar filtering.

Since all five newspapers rely on  the same data source, they are subject to similar filtering.

Comment: It should be "rely **on**".

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is understandable with *likewise*, but I have some reservations about using it that way.  "Likewise" emphasizes how the other four are the same as the first.  That image is slightly incongruous with "All", which treats all five newspapers as a unified group.

You don't really need any adverb there, but if you want to one for emphasis, I would say

> All five newspapers rely **on** the same data source, so all are **equally** subject to the same filtering.

Arguably, "equally" and "same" are somewhat redundant.

(Your original sentence was missing a preposition.  "Rely" is an intransitive verb.)

Answer (score 0):

> All five newspapers rely **on** the same data source, so all are
>   **similarly** subject to the same filtering.

If the objective is to emphasize the fluidity of the entire enterprise, then using the alliteration of similarly and same could be useful. Otherwise, the subsequent @Spare1Rib4me is probably the most correct in that it is simpler:

> All newspapers rely on the same data, hence they are all subject to
>   the same filtering.

In terms of the most informative answer regarding grammar, @200_success provided a good summary except equally may be too general:

> All five newspapers rely **on** the same data source, so all are
>   **equally** subject to the same filtering.

Since we are talking about specific newspapers which are subject to filtering, we could reword as: Newspapers are similar subjects to the filter (not the same or equal from the filters perspective). In the context of the sentence this could be changed to "similarly subject."

There is a nice table of Conjunctive Adverbs and the Relation They Indicate here http://englishmistakeswelcome.com/conjunctions.htm

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @ColleenV Ok, will try to fix it as my answer was formatted as a comment to which my mobile app responded with an access error